# How do I add +1 in jQuery each time a specific element on page loads and write it to a span/div?

Tags: jquery

I have a large page running a loop (ASP Classic) that loads many tables/divs containing data for each users. On the same page I have a Loading DIV that hides when entire content is loaded, but I would like to add a counter that shows the user that X of X elements have been loaded, so I have tried to do this with the  below jQuery script, but I am not able to get it to count for each loop, the number remains 0.

In the Preloader I have:

```
<span id="UsersLoadedCountDisplay">0<span>
```

I have tried both these scripts:

```
var UsersLoadedCount = $(“#UsersLoadedCountDisplay”).val();
```

and

```
var UsersLoadedCount  = +$(“#UsersLoadedCountDisplay”).val() + 1;
```

and after each loop I have placed the following to make the increment to UsersLoadedCountDisplay:

```
UsersLoadedCount = parseInt(UsersLoadedCount) + 1;
```

Am I totally way off? ..or what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The span has no value. Its a text. You can use `parseInt()`

```js
setInterval(function() {
    console.log("A user has been loaded");
    $("#UsersLoadedCountDisplay").text(parseInt($("#UsersLoadedCountDisplay").text())+1);
  }, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="UsersLoadedCountDisplay">0<span>
```

Comment: Brilliant @Prosy Arceno, that is a very nice way to do it, works like a charm!! Thank you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    
            var counter = 0;
       
            $(document).ready(function() {
                     counter++;
       
                    $("#theCount").text(counter);
                });
           </script>
    </head>    
    <body>
        <div id="theCount"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Counter is 0 but onload it will add 1 which the counter onload will be 1.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can't use `val()` to read a content of a span, you should use `text()` and then after incrementing, you'll have to put the count back in the span.

```
var count = +$('#UsersLoadedCountDisplay').text() + 1;
$('#UsersLoadedCountDisplay').text(count);
```